# LEFT JOIN like hasMany in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, left-join, has-many

Is there a way to manage LEFT JOIN which gives similar results like hasMany in CakePHP?

Let's say that I have two tables:

owners:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Paul |
|  2 | Adam |
|  3 | John |
+----+------+
```

shops:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id |   name   | owner_id |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Grocery1 |        1 |
|  2 | Grocery2 |        1 |
|  3 | Grocery3 |        2 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Now I would like to have result like:

```
[0] => array
    (
        [Owner] => array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => Paul
            )
        [Shop] => array
            [0] => array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Grocery1
                )
            [1] => array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Grocery2
                )
    )
```

and so on

When I use hasMany, results are ok, all shops are nested to the owner but when I have lots of database records, it makes tons of mysql queries.

When i do join, there is good amount of queries but i have one shop - one owner result.

Is there a proper way to make all shops nested array to the Owner ?

Thanks

Comment: I do not know if I understood your question right. But you're talking about `belongsTo`?

Comment: When You use belongsTo, You have to have shop_id in owner table. If you additionaly use 'foreign_key' => false and set proper conditions it behaves same like hasMany - tons of queries.

Comment: Any reason to prefer join over hasMany?

Comment: Having lots of records in database, for every owner there are new queries for shops. Because of that i have more than 200 queries and page loads slowly.